# Python3 pip install git-pre-push-hook

Tags: python-3.x, git, ubuntu, pip, installation

I tried to install the module [git-pre-push-hook](https://github.com/kkujawinski/git-pre-push-hook) with:

```
pip3 install git-pre-push-hook
mkdir test 
cd test 
git init 
touch README.md 
install-git-pre-push-hook
```

But this error is thrown after using the command `install-git-pre-push-hook`
Any idea why this happens?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tim/.local/bin/install-git-pre-push-hook", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/tim/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/git_pre_push_hook/install.py", line 18, in main
    os.path.abspath(git_dir.strip()), 'hooks', 'pre-push'
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/posixpath.py", line 94, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/genericpath.py", line 151, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError("Can't mix strings and bytes in path components") from None
TypeError: Can't mix strings and bytes in path components
```

Comment: There might be an issue with your local python. What is your python version?

Comment: Python2.7.15rc1 and Python3.6.6

Comment: You can use Docker to check if the problem is on your PC, or with this package. Get a plain image with P2 or P3 and try it out. And may I suggest another hook tool? https://pypi.org/project/hooks4git